# MYSQL: Count the number of times a value appears in results without running the query recursively

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I've been googling and reviewing SO posts, still unsure of how to accomplish this.

I have a table of results, grouped by (user, due date), 
counting the number of items for each due date for each user.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    userid as user, 
    nextduedate as due_date, 
    count(th.id) as services 
FROM 
    `tblhosting` th 
    JOIN `tblcustomfieldsvalues` tcfv on th.userid = tcfv.relid
    JOIN `tblclients` tc on th.userid = tc.id
WHERE 
    th.domainstatus = 'Active' 
    AND (th.nextduedate > date(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 day)) AND th.nextduedate < date(DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 month))) 
    AND th.packageid NOT IN (132, 130, 129)
    AND tcfv.fieldid = 55
    AND tcfv.value = "on"
    AND tc.separateinvoices = 0
GROUP BY userid, nextduedate
ORDER BY userid asc
```

Results:

```
| user | due_date   | services |
|------|------------|----------|
| 77   | 2019-03-10 | 4        |
| 81   | 2019-03-05 | 23       |
| 99   | 2019-03-10 | 97       |
| 455  | 2019-03-13 | 9        |
| 478  | 2019-03-10 | 18       |
| 491  | 2019-03-03 | 1        |
| 491  | 2019-03-10 | 143      |
| 541  | 2019-03-02 | 2        |
| 541  | 2019-03-10 | 68       |
| 575  | 2019-03-02 | 46       |
```

User 491 has 1 service due on 03-03 and 143 due on 03-10.

I need to count the number of times each user appears in the list, as I'm looking specifically for users with more than 1 due date.

This is actually quite easy in theory, as I can do an outer select like so:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) 
FROM (inner select) a
GROUP BY a.userid
```

This will give me:

```
| user | count(userid)|
|------|--------------|
| 77   | 1            |
| 81   | 1            |
| 99   | 1            |
| 455  | 1            |
| 478  | 1            |
| 491  | 2            |
| 541  | 2            |
| 575  | 1            |
```

Then I can left join this result to the original results, but it requires running the query twice. Something like

```
Select * FROM 
(

  Inner Select a
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) FROM 
    (inner select) a
    GROUP BY a.userid
    ) b ON a.userid = b.userid 
  where x and y
) c
```

With this, I have to run the original select (as inner select), group and count it (to get the counts), then join it to the original select which is quite inefficient and increases the runtime exponentially.

For the sake of efficiency I would like to count the number of times each user appears in the original results by referring to the result set. I need to preserve the different due dates for each user so I cant simply group by userid.

It would ideally look like this:

```
| user | due_date   | services | counts |
|------|------------|----------|--------|
| 77   | 2019-03-10 | 4        | 1      |
| 81   | 2019-03-05 | 23       | 1      |
| 99   | 2019-03-10 | 97       | 1      |
| 455  | 2019-03-13 | 9        | 1      |
| 478  | 2019-03-10 | 18       | 1      |
| 491  | 2019-03-03 | 1        | 2      |
| 491  | 2019-03-10 | 143      | 2      |
| 541  | 2019-03-02 | 2        | 2      |
| 541  | 2019-03-10 | 68       | 2      |
| 575  | 2019-03-02 | 46       | 1      |
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL 8.0, use window functions :

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t.user) AS counts
FROM (
    -- your query
) AS t
```

---

With older versions of MySQL, neither window functions nor Common Table Expressions are available. I would compute the results for the two levels of aggregation in two distinct (although almost identical) subqueries, and then `JOIN` their results :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.counts
FROM (
    SELECT userid as user, nextduedate as due_date, count(th.id) as services 
    FROM 
        `tblhosting` th 
        JOIN `tblcustomfieldsvalues` tcfv on th.userid = tcfv.relid
        JOIN `tblclients` tc on th.userid = tc.id
    WHERE 
        th.domainstatus = 'Active' 
        AND (th.nextduedate > date(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 day)) AND th.nextduedate < date(DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 month))) 
        AND th.packageid NOT IN (132, 130, 129)
        AND tcfv.fieldid = 55 and tcfv.value = "on"
        AND tc.separateinvoices = 0
    GROUP BY userid, nextduedate
) t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT userid, count(th.id) as counts 
    FROM 
        `tblhosting` th 
        JOIN `tblcustomfieldsvalues` tcfv on th.userid = tcfv.relid
        JOIN `tblclients` tc on th.userid = tc.id
    WHERE 
        th.domainstatus = 'Active' 
        AND (th.nextduedate > date(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 day)) AND th.nextduedate < date(DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 month))) 
        AND th.packageid NOT IN (132, 130, 129)
        AND tcfv.fieldid = 55 and tcfv.value = "on"
        AND tc.separateinvoices = 0
    GROUP BY userid
) t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
ORDER BY t1.userid
```

Comment: Wow, this makes me very excited for what MySQL 8.0 has to offer, thanks! I should've mentioned that our environment requires 5.7 and it is impossible to upgrade until our 3rd party software supports 8.0 :/

Comment: @Andrew : too bad... OK, I updated my answer with a solution for MySQL < 8.0, which is less elegant but should work.

Comment: That's what I feared, thanks for the update. I greatly appreciate your mentioning of both CTE's and Window functions as the options for better solutions, these are both new to me and have pointed me to new places to learn/research. Additionally the complete solution using an inner join is better than what I came up with (multiple outer selects) so hats off and a big thanks to you sir! Cheers